# UPDATE statement that updates any field with a specific value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I just learned how to make update statements in SQL and I think it may be useful for another issue I'm having.

I need to set any column that has a value of 999 to an asterisk. I have an access database being populated by a dynamometer automatically. There are several fields that could have this high value (upwards of 114).

From what I gather I could explicitly state each potential field followed by a where criteria:

```
SET field1 = "*", field2 = "*", .. field114 = "*" WHERE field1 = 999.. etc
```

Is there a simple way of stating all fields? There shouldn't be a test where 999 was a result and it wasn't an error to be ignored.

Comment: I think sql is preferred since I'm using it pretty heavily in vba currently, but if there's an Access-specific solution I'm not opposed to it. I am trying to avoid using DAO because I think that requires looping and there's potential to have to loop through thousands of records (with almost 500 fields to probably loop through as well).

Comment: Use _null_ instead of *.

Comment: @jarlh I wasn't sure if null would work or not. We use a different program that specifically uses asterisks to ignore values and thankfully if the value is null the program translates to an asterisk. Thankfully so because I'm pretty sure asterisk would be a string but these fields are doubles. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling many fields equally is a clear indicator of a non-normalized database design, as is having 114 fields. That likely is your underlying problem, and fixing that will make update operations much easier.

In update queries, you need to specify every field. You can use the following construction to update fields that are 999 to *, but it's somewhat bad practice, as it touches rows even if no fields have a value of 999

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
Field1 = IIF(Field1 = "999", "*", Field1),
Field2 = IIF(Field2 = "999", "*", Field2),
etc
```

Comment: It was a pain in the posterior but specifying each field works. And despite looking at almost every single value in the query, there's no noticeable delay.